# Android sms reading by number

Tags: android, android-contentprovider

I am working on a sms application. in my App I have to list all the convrsation .SO i use the following Uri.

```
content://mms-sms/conversations/
```

Its working fine.And the following is my code snippet.

```
 Uri uri = Uri.parse("content://mms-sms/conversations/");
 Cursor c= getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null ,null,null);
 startManagingCursor(c);
 if(c.moveToFirst()){

            for(int i=0;i<c.getCount();i++){
                     body[i]= c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("body")).toString();
                     number[i]=c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("address")).toString();
                     c.moveToNext();
             }
    }
    c.close();

    for (int i = 0; i < body.length; i++) {
        System.out.println("body ="+body[i]);
        System.out.println("number ="+number[i]);
    }
```

The number prints each conversations number and body prints the each conversations last message. But i want to get each conversations whole message and also help me to conversation for a specific number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From `Conversations`cursor, You can get `thread_id`. Once you got `thread_id`, continue query from `sms provider` to return all message which has the same `thread_id`

Example : `thread_id` = 2

```
Uri SMS_INBOX = Uri.parse("content://sms");
Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(SMS_INBOX, null, "thread_id" + " = "
                + "2", null,
                "date" + " ASC");


while (c.moveToNext()){

        Log.v("BODY", c.getString(11).toString()); // 11 is the index of body with project URI

    }
```

Comment: @Pkmmte: Change URI. You can search on SO. Sorry i haven't worked with Android for along time so i don't remember